# can tree-based models extrapolate with categorical independent variables

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, random-forest, cart, boosting

I am aware of the fact that tree-based (machine learning) models struggle to extrapolate - see regression example [here](https://neptune.ai/blog/random-forest-regression-when-does-it-fail-and-why). I am only familiar with the concept of extrapolation for numeric independent variables. AFIK whether an independent variable is numeric or categorical, does not really matter for tree-based models. So can I conclude, that tree-based models can also not extrapolate for  categorical independent variables? Which model can extrapolate for categorical independent variables, if this concept actually exist for categorical independent variables?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by tree based models do not extrapolate on numeric independent variables?

Comment: Please refer this as an example: (see extrapolation problem) https://neptune.ai/blog/random-forest-regression-when-does-it-fail-and-why

Comment: This is about dependent variable as usual. I wonder what you mean by extrapolation on the independent var.

Comment: ah I see what you mean. yes you are right. sorry I expressed this clumsily. the example I added has a numeric IV and a numeric DV (aka regression). I wonder if this issues also exists with categorical IVs? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tree based methods predict the target (dependent) variable as the averages of the leaf values. The values in the leaves occurs in the training set, so you can't get an out of range output from the trees. This could happen even if the features (independent variables) are in their respective training data ranges.

But, a new value (extrapolation in your saying) for a categorical variable (IV) breaks the model. And this is not particular to tree based algorithms. With a new surprise category, you won't be able to execute a linear regression well (or at all).

Comment: Thanks. Are there no models to avoid this issue?

Comment: You can handle it by defining an "Others" category, but can't completely avoid its effects as you encounter a new category in the test set, which you do not know anything about.

Comment: There's random effects models, which can predict for a new categorical level (will treat it as an average new category with extra uncertainty according to the between category variation).